# Testing output of $q.all in angular controller

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

My controller does something like below (pls note i had not shown all dependencies for sake of simplicity):

```
.controller('demo',function(){

      fn1(){
          var defereed = $q.defer;
          /* fetch data from server and once the data is fetched perform a resolve */
          return deferred.promise;
      }

     fn2(){
        var defereed = $q.defer;
          /* fetch data from server and once the data is fetched perform a resolve*/      
          return deferred.promise;
     }

     fun3() { /*makes some server side calls and updates the view*/}

     $q.all([fn1(),fn2()] .then(function(result){
           if (result[0]) { fn3();}
       });

    }
```

Under such circumstances I have having a hard time testing whether fn3() was called. I am also not able to get fn1() and fn2() to resolve so that i can test fn3()

Any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: You should use $httpBackend to mock the server

Comment: dont' think $httpBackend applies here..

Answer (score 0):

Finally figuered a solution .. For those interested check this plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/HkaQdH

```
describe('Testing: MainCtrl', function() {
  var $scope = null;
  var ctrl = null;
  var mockInitService;
  var defer1,defer2;
  var $q;

  beforeEach(module('plunker'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller,$q) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $q = $q;

    mockInitService = {
      fn1: function(){},
      fn2: function(){},
      fn3: function(){}
    };
    defer1 = $q.defer();
    defer2 = $q.defer();

    spyOn(mockInitService,'fn1').and.returnValue(defer1.promise);
    spyOn(mockInitService,'fn2').and.returnValue(defer2.promise);
    spyOn(mockInitService,'fn3');

    createController = function() {
      return $controller('MainCtrl', {
        $scope: $scope,
        InitService: mockInitService
      });
    }

  }));

  it('Should call InitService.fn3', function() {
    ctrl = createController();
    defer1.resolve();
    defer2.resolve();
    $scope.$digest();
    expect(mockInitService.fn3).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```